# Как удалить MySQL и установить MariaDB в Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Хочу установить **MariaDB**, сейчас установлено **MySQL**. Как мне полностью удалить **MySQL**(вместе с паролями и тд) и установить **MariaDB** в **Ubuntu**?
Сейчас при установке MariaDB :

*A file named /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag exists on this system. 
 Really proceed with downgrade?*

После подтверждения получаю ошибку:

invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-5.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `apt-get purge mysql5-server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ:
 - cd /var/lib
 - sudo service mysql stop
 - sudo cp -R mysql _mysql
 - sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
 - sudo rm -R mysql
 - sudo apt-get install mariadb-client mariadb-server
 - sudo cp -Ruv _mysql/. mysql/.
 - sudo rm -R _mysql